# InstallShield: Install Level

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have an InstallShield Project that has 3 features.

One of the Features I need to be installable via Custom Install, but not install by default.

I am looking at the Feature's Install Level, which is currently 1.

Can I use this to make it not installed by default?

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the [INSTALLLEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369536(v=vs.85).aspx) property in the installer to something like 100. Then any feature you want installed by default set its install level to something below or equal to 100. Any feature you want installed only when selected then set its install level to a number above 100.